# Generating symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, arrows

I would like to use symbol [image: Crossed Arrow] in my thesis, so please is it possible

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! This isn't by any chance for chemistry, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I define it as `\strokearrow`.  If different stroke sizes are preferred, or if it is needed in `\scriptstyle`, etc., please let me know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\strokearrow{%
  \mathrel{\stackengine{0pt}{$\rightarrow$}{$/\mkern -6mu/\mkern4mu$}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\begin{document}
$A \strokearrow B \rightarrow C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one actually wanted a longer arrow shaft, then perhaps this would do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\strokearrow{\mathrel{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{$-\mkern-8mu\rightarrow$}{$/\mkern -6mu/\mkern-2mu$}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\begin{document}
$A \strokearrow B \rightarrow C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @adghjifa You are most welcome.  And welcome to the site.  Happy LaTeXing!

Answer (score 4):

An application of standard tricks with `\mathpalette` and `\ooalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\strokearrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\stroke@arrow{/}}}
\newcommand{\dstrokearrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\stroke@arrow{/\!\!/}}}
\newcommand{\stroke@arrow}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1#2$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1\longrightarrow$\cr}%
  \vphantom{#2}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\strokearrow B_{\strokearrow}$

$A\dstrokearrow B_{\dstrokearrow}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is this (by any chance) for a chemical reaction?

- reaction with `chemformula`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{chemformula}
  \begin{document}

  \ch{ A + B -/> C }

  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]
- reaction with `chemfig`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{chemfig}
  \begin{document}

  \schemestart
    A \+ B \arrow{-/>} C
  \schemestop

  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]

Comment: That symbol was used to represent parallel reduction  in lambda calculus, it was taken from this paper

[link]https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2588155_Polishing_Up_the_Tait-Martin-Lof_Proof_of_the_Church-Rosser_Theorem